# How to overlay bounding box information onto a JPG and create a PDF

Tags: .net-core, pdf-generation, ocr

Context: Atm we are using Googles Tesseract for OCR purpuses. The which creates (given the right configuration) a PDF that contains the initial graphics with an overlay of the extracted/OCRed text.

For various reasons we want to move to MS Cognition Services which will return us
something like this

```
{
  "language": "en",
  "textAngle": -2.0000000000000338,
  "orientation": "Up",
  "regions": [
    {
      "boundingBox": "462,379,497,258",
      "lines": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "462,379,497,74",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "462,379,41,73",
              "text": "A"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "523,379,153,73",
              "text": "GOAL"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "694,379,265,74",
              "text": "WITHOUT"
            }
          ]
        },
}
```

So I get the extracted text and the bounding boxes but I dont get a PDF and the overlay which I still need.

How can create a PDF file that takes a graphics file and bounding box information?
The Solution should work on either .dotnet or nodejs.

Comment: *"Can anybody point me to .dotnet (or nodejs) libraries that"* - library recommendations strictly speaking are off topic here and should be asked for on the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Removed the reference about asking about a library ;-) I hope its better now

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this as well. It is helpful to compare visually the results of the AI to the original PDF to see exactly how the computer interpreted the image and what the results were. It helps when users aren't 100% confident in the results and need to recheck everything.

Comment: Have you tried to create one canvas for one returned 'text' boundingbox, then positions all the canvases in one page for PDF generation by C#? Cutting the bounding box as an image from original image should not be difficult.